# Ruby string with '.' to snake case

Tags: ruby

I've got string `'client.status'` which I want to convert to snakecase - `client_status`. Is there a quick way to do so?

I tried:

```
> 'client.status'.underscore
"client.status"

> 'client.status'.parameterize
"client-status"

> 'client.status'.parameterize('_')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):81
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))
```

Comment: Replace the dot yourself (with `gsub`, `tr` or others)?

Comment: When you are unsure about the arguments or run into an `ArgumentError` you should consult the docs for the method: [`String#parameterize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-parameterize)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing the separator, you need to provide it as the keyword argument.

```
'client.status'.parameterize(separator: '_')
```

For more information, the source of the code is:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb, line 190
  def parameterize(separator: "-", preserve_case: false)
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.parameterize(self, separator: separator, preserve_case: preserve_case)
  end
```